# Does the assignment operator consume memory in Java?

Tags: java, variable-assignment

I have some two Strings as below:

`"yes", "no"`.

Now, I would like to compare these Strings in two ways:

1. Directly: 
   Example: `"yes".equals("no")`
2. By assigning the strings to some variable:
   Example:

   ```
   String string1 = "yes";
   String string2 ="no";
   string1.equals(string2);
   ```

In these two cases, is there any memory or performance difference?

Comment: the same performance

Comment: It's hard to reason about such small code snippets. Whether or not the variables are referenced elsewhere, whether they are assigned to, and whether or not the result of `equals` is actually stored or used can greatly impact what code the compiler decides to output.

Comment: This way of thinking about programming will lead you to write unreadable code with no increase in performance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a very minor difference (effectively negligible, we're talking micro-optimization here), since the string should be stored in a local variable which takes that extra bit of memory on the stack frame of the corresponding method. Whereas the constants are actually stored in the constant pool and shared. With the likely optimizations of the JVM based on the number of invocations, it won't make a difference.

Note that the bytecode would be the same if the variables were `final` or effectively `final` (assigned only once), since in this case they are treated as constants.

Comment: *Note that there would be no difference if the variables were final, in which case they are effectively treated as constants.* > Also note that, given the variables are not reassigned somewhere elsewhere in the code, the compiler will recognize them as implicitly "final" and do the same optimizations that would be done if the `final` keyword was explicitly used.

Comment: I don't think the heap is involved here. They are references to strings in the constant pool. The reference variables are kept on the stack, AFAIK.

Comment: In our code if we do this assignment some 100 times. Then is it consumes memory and performance?

Comment: Puce is right. As the strings are constant, they would be stored in the constant pool and loaded onto the stack with the `ldc` opcode, not copied to the heap. The variables will probably get wiped by the compiler if they aren't referenced elsewhere. (That is assuming of course that the compiler isn't clever enough to inline this as a constant false, since `String` is `final` and the implementation of `String.equals` is unlikely to change.)

Comment: @Puce You're absolutely right. They're on the stack.

Comment: @SaikiranGosikonda I don't think 100 times would cause a noticeable difference. I would waste time optimizing somewhere else in the code.

Comment: We're talking *pico-optimization* here.

Comment: Note that the compiler may have to allocate slots in the frame (this is necessary so that the bytecode can be verified at class loading time), but the JIT can use registers directly. If this code is in a hot loop (note to OP: 100 iterations is nowhere near a real hot loop -- try 100 million iterations) then the JIT is likely to generate the most efficient machine code possible regardless of whether you're using different variables or not.

Comment: Is there any reliable source that the compiler is doing an optimization regarding this issue?

Answer (score 10):

Compiling these code snippets will result in **the same** bytecode. Hence, there is no memory consumption or performance difference.

The assignment operator **never** consume memory (except the case of autoboxing: `Integer number = 42`). Local variable declaration may allocate memory in stack (if it necessary), but you should prefer code readability.

Comment: For numbers less than some constant (128?), autoboxing consumes no memory either.

Comment: @Cephalopod You're right, for numbers in range [-128, 127] it is guaranteed by JLS7 5.1.7

Comment: Note that the upper bound can be modified so I doubt it is explicitely guaranteed.

Comment: @fRoStBiT please add a link to the guarantee.  Google failed me.

Comment: @MSmith It's here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7

Answer (score 7):

Depending on the compiler it might take the space of 2 additional object references on the stack, I guess. These are small enough you usually can ignore them unless you profiled your application and you spotted an issue there (very unlikely).

> "yes".equals("no")

In real code there is hardly ever a situation like this, as you would already know if 2 literals are the same or not.